# Custom Contextual Table Row Class Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create some custom classes for contextual TR colorisation using Bootstrap.

Reading the documentation it says to find the copy the class property to a custom.css file and modify it suit your needs. However after trying this without success I thought I would add my custom class into bootstrap.css. Still this resulted in no success.

I have been looking to try and diagnose the problem using Firebug but haven't been able to find a solution, hence the post here.

When I use the class element 'success' the CSS looks like this

```
.table-bordered thead:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > td:first-child, .table-bordered tfoot:last-child tr:last-child > th:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.table tbody tr.success > td {
    background-color: #DFF0D8;
}
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

when I use my custom class (which I can see is selected in Firebug) I get this.

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td, .table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th {
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

So its not even reading the custom class from the CSS file and I have no idea why.

Any thoughts?

S

EDIT ******

The custom CSS file looks like this.

```
.width100{
    width: 100%;    
}

/*Custom Table Row Property*/
.table-striped> tbody tr.major > td {
  background-color: #faa732;
}

.table tbody tr.initial > td {
  background-color: #49afcd;
}

.table tbody tr.maint > td {
  background-color: #5b331d;
} 

.table tbody tr.suppressed > td {
  background-color: #bfcada;
}
```

Comment: what does the css from your custom class look like?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by the browser cache. Too localized.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out that Firefox had cached the CSS files and I have spent hours tracking down an issue cause by the browser!!!

Cleared the cache and it worked correctly straight away.

DAMN IT!!!!